# Count the number of unique values based on two columns in a spreadsheet

Tags: command-line, sed, awk, csv

I need to count the number of unique values based on two columns in a spreadsheet.

Suppose the file looks like this, ordered by name, surname, company:

```
joe allen ibm
joe smith ibm
joe allen google
joe smith google
rachel allen google
```

And I need to count the number of unique first names for each company while ignoring the surname:

```
joe ibm 2
joe google 2
rachel google 1
```

I have this code:

```
sort file.tsv | uniq -ci | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

If I simply delete the surname column, that code will work. But if I don't want to delete that column, just have awk ignore it, and save the output to a new file?

The data is separated by tabs `\t`

Comment: But your output doesn't contain the surname, so why bother keeping it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A GNU awk solution using [two-dimensional arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html):

```
gawk -F $'\t' '{a[$1][$3]++} END {for (i in a) for (j in a[i]) print i, j, a[i][j]}' foo.txt
```

- `a[$1][$3]++` for each combination of first name and surname, increment the count
- Then loop through the first names and the company names associated with each first name.

Another way that will work other `awk`s using the older form of multidimensional arrays:

```
awk -F $'\t' '{a[$1, $3]++} END{for (i in a) {split (i, sep, SUBSEP); print sep[1], sep[2], a[i]}}' foo.txt
```

- Since the old method actually uses a concatenation of the indices separated by `SUBSEP`, we have to split on `SUBSEP` to get back the original indices.

Comment: Ah thanks so much for your help! The data is actually separated by \t, how can I split on \t in the second code you wrote?

Comment: You can specify the field separator: `-F $'\t'`

Comment: Thanks, but how would the one-liner look like if I implement -F $'\t'? I tried to replace SUBSEP with this, but it didn't work. My apologies for all the questions, I'm new to awk!

Comment: See the update. I assume you meant a tab character not literally a backslash followed by t.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Pythonic solution using the `Counter` class of `collections` module which will count the number of occurrences of each element in an iterable:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import collections
with open('file.txt') as f:
    names = []
    for line in f:
        names.append(line.strip().split()[0] + ' ' + line.strip().split()[2])
    result_dict = collections.Counter(names)
    for person in result_dict:
        print person + ' ' + str(result_dict[person])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `cut` to select the columns you want to operate on first. So given that your columns are separated by a space, and are FNAME SNAME COMPANY where we are only interested in column 1 and 3 we can use:

```
cut -d' ' -f1,3 file.tsv | sort | uniq -ci
```

This tells `cut` to separate using a single space ' ' as a delimeter and to pass columns 1 and 3 into sort.

It will produce some output similar to:

```
 cut -d' ' -f1,3 file.tsv | sort | uniq -ci
      2 joe google
      2 joe ibm
      1 rachel google
```

Answer (score 2):

The following perl oneliner will extract the data for you:

```
perl -e '/(.*)\t.*\t(.*)/ and $a{"$1 $2"}++ for (<>); print "$_ $a{$_}\n" foreach (keys%a);' file.tsv
```

Output:

```
joe ibm 2
joe google 2
rachel google 1
```

Comment: Thanks Sylvian! This uses regex, right? What would the oneliner look like if the data is separated by \t, not whitespace?

Comment: the regexp is using `\t`, I've updated the answer a few minutes ago

Comment: Awesome, thanks Sylvian! It works, I will come back to upvote your answer when I have a good enough rep.